# How do I apply text justify on Bootstrap alerts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to ask how to justify (right and left aligned) text inside Bootstrap alerts. I tried to use class text-justify with alert classes but could not get the text to be justified. Code is as follows:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-error text-justify">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque enim non dolor blandit lobortis. Aenean risus elit, porta eu consectetur vel, mollis ut risus
</div>.
```

So far, I'm getting the output below:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Link to bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/d3oeN9GlOg

Change your code like this and see.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-error text-justify">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque enim       non dolor blandit lobortis. Aenean risus elit, porta eu consectetur vel, mollis ut risus
  </div>
</div>
```

The **container** div is optional.

If you don't want the container and want the close button and other elements in the same line, use this code instead.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-error text-justify">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque scelerisque enim non dolor blandit lobortis. Aenean risus elit, porta eu consectetur vel, mollis ut risus 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the updated bootply: http://www.bootply.com/tyrOuAN0x0

Comment: Worked perfectly! I've removed the container div and added margin-bottom:-15px style on div row to align the text with the close link. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use negative margin. Instead try this: http://www.bootply.com/tyrOuAN0x0 . Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Just did that. Thanks again!

Comment: :) When you use bootstrap, use it everywhere :D